# Magento 1.9 customer/account throwing 404 error

Tags: magento

I run a webstore using Magento 1.9 , on clicking  on account it is throwing /customer/account gets a Magento 404 error.

I have the same issues with the admin panel as well, as I am able to edit the old customer in admin panel but not the new customer registerd after 404 error.

I have also gone through the [here](http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages) but not able to find the correct solution.

Comment: check if `.htaccess` file is present in root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

There were records for this customer in the previous store. This prevented me to add the customer in the new updated store. I have deleted all the previous records and it works fine :)